# "Be in a coat" or "have a coat on"?

Tags: phrase-usage

Tell me please if *be in a coat* and *have a coat on* are equally used and correct. For example:

> I won't get cold as I am in a warm coat.
>
> I won't get cold as I have a warm coat on.

Answer (score 1):

"I won't get cold as I have a warm coat on" or "I won't get cold as I am wearing a warm coat" are the two ways you would most likely hear it expressed. (Note: "because" instead of "as" would also work, and may be more common.)

Comment: or in spoken english with neither "I won't get cold, I have a warm coat on"

Comment: We _do_ speak of someone being _in uniform_ or _in their pyjamas_ (dressed in a certain way), but _in_ is not normally used of an extra garment like an outdoor coat.